# Remove Empty Cells in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently working with a table in BigQuery and I am not able to remove rows where there is nothing in the cell (the cell is empty). It is not a NULL value but just an empty string for a column of type String.

Here is the example:
[table that contains blank cell in the columns *ways*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nSf1.png)

I tried doing:
`WHERE ways IS NOT NULL`
`WHERE LENGTH(ways) > 0`
`WHERE ways <> ''`
`WHERE ways != ''`

But the empty cells still stay there after my query. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try trim(ways) ...

Comment: It doesn't work I still get the empty cells. What I did: `SELECT title, trim(ways) as ways, k FROM all_join`

Comment: In where clause!!